# Get the currently displayed image from a browser page with javascript

Tags: javascript, google-chrome

Have searched high and low and can't find an answer to this.
My problem from a tech pov is exactly like the one I'm describing, but using https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/ is easier.

Say, I have a website like https://thispersondoesnotexist.com/ where the 's src is a page that always returns a new image.

But I want to grab the currently displayed one, base64 encode it and save it to a variable.

How can I do that in Chrome with Javascript.

Comment: most easily with tampermonkey

Comment: I need to do it with just javascript

Comment: who is "we", do you have write access to said site, what did you try, what is "not" javascript about tampermonkey (wich is the only solution apart from bookmarklets unless you have write access to said site)

Comment: We = I. Tampermonkey is an extension, I want to do it with your good ol' JS.

Comment: It's a third party site that I don't own.